# Matthews Correlation Coefficient in Lasso model, logistic regression with R

Tags: r, mcc

I am using data (birthwt) from the library (MASS) and I'd like to calculate Mathews Correlation Coefficient (MCC) with R in a Lasso model. I am really confused. Thks in advance

```
birthwt=birthwt[,-10]
boot=sample(nrow(birthwt), 40)
train.data=birthwt[-boot, ]
test.data=birthwt[boot, ]
x =model.matrix(low~., train.data)[,-1]
y =train.data$low
```

## Lasso Model:

```
library(glmnet)
set.seed(123)
cv.lasso = cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha = 1, family = "binomial")
model.lasso=glmnet(x,y,alpha=1,family="binomial",lambda= cv.lasso$lambda.min)
coef(model.lasso)
 x.test = model.matrix(low ~., test.data)[,-1]
proba.lasso = predict(model.lasso,newx = x.test)
class.lasso = ifelse(proba.lasso > 0.5, 1, 0)
class.obs = test.data$low
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do predict on a glmnet object, the default response is the logit link, but in your case, you need to do:

```
class.lasso = predict(model.lasso,newx = x.test,type="class")
class.lasso = as.numeric(class.lasso)
class.obs = test.data$low
```

You can also use the probability this way:

```
class.lasso = ifelse(predict(model.lasso,newx = x.test,type="response") > 0.5,1,0)
```

To calculate mcc, you can do:

```
library(mltools)
mcc(pred = class.lasso, actual = class.obs)
[1] 0.2581989
```

Or use something that calculates pearson's phi:

```
library(psych)
phi(table(class.lasso,class.obs),digits=7)

[1] 0.2581989
```

Or if you derive it from scratch using [the formula from wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthews_correlation_coefficient):

```
cm = table(class.lasso,class.obs)
TP = cm[2,2]
FP = cm[2,1]
TN = cm[1,1]
FN = cm[1,2]

(TP * TN - FP*FN)/sqrt((TP+FP)*(TP+FN)*(TN+FP)*(TN+FN))
[1] 0.2581989
```

Comment: Very clear and quick. Thank you. 
Any way to calculate the Accuracy, sensitivity and sensibility for the model?

Comment: you can use confusionMatrix from the package caret. Do ```confusionMatrix(table(class.lasso,class.obs))```

Comment: it doesn't work: Error in confusionMatrix_(actual, predicted, cutoff) : 
  argument "predicted" is missing, with no default
Otherwise, for the first code: class.lasso = predict(model.lasso,newx = x.test,type="class"), is it porba.lasso (as I wrote it) or class.lasso?

Comment: you are missing the ```table()``` . it is class lasso. Hey I have to say this, if you have additional questions, please post another question. If you repeat my code above, for sure you can get MCC. can you please try that and don't detour

Comment: see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40451926/how-to-send-a-confusion-matrix-to-carets-confusionmatrix, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33431694/caret-package-defining-positive-result/33432399#33432399 and such for specificity and sensitivity